# Jquery: select only some set from selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a requirement where I have to filter only portion of my whole selection. Here is example

```
<li class="link">one</li>
<li class="link">two</li>
<li class="link">three</li>
<li class="link">four</li>
<li class="link">five</li>
<li class="link">six</li>
<li class="link">seven</li>
<li class="link">eight</li>
<li class="link">nine</li>
<li class="link">ten</li>
```

my requirement is to filter element from "three" to "five" and have to apply some highlights on them. I don't want to use looping and looking for some elegent filtering syntax. 
I tried something like $(".link:gt(2),lt(5)") but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
$(".link")​.slice(2,5)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JYLpr/

Comment: I got different answer for my question but this is exactly what i want. Thanks wirey

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the selectors normally one after the other, also `:gt` and `:lt` are zero based

```
 $(".link:gt(1):lt(3)")
```

Comment: Actually it should be `$(".link:gt(1):lt(3)")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code its working for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
for(var i=1;i<=10;i++){
 $("#test"+i).css('display','none');
}
for(var i=4;i<=8;i++)
{
    $("#test"+i).css('font-family','Rupee Foradian,Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif');
 $("#test"+i).css('font-weight','bold');
 $("#test"+i).css('display','block');
}
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<li class="link" id="test1">one</li>
<li class="link" id="test2">two</li>
<li class="link" id="test3">three</li>
<li class="link" id="test4">four</li>
<li class="link" id="test5">five</li>
<li class="link" id="test6">six</li>
<li class="link" id="test7">seven</li>
<li class="link" id="test8">eight</li>
<li class="link" id="test9">nine</li>
<li class="link" id="test10">ten</li>
<button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```